# Given a set of coordinates, find the max distance (using steps)

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, path, coordinates

Given a set of coordinates representing a flight path, the exercice is to  find the maximum distance (given a n number of points to pass through). To illustrate the problem we have a flight path represented on a 2D grid as the following:

[image: Flight Path].

Here is what the algorithm should do with a parameter n (integer).

[image: Find max distance]

The question is to find an algorithm that can scan through all the points and try by combination all the distances and return the length of the final path.

We already have a method that can get the distance of two points:

```
 /**
 * @return the distance between the two coordinates
 */
public double distance(Coordinate destination) {}

 /**
 * @return the farthest coordinate from start
 */
public Coordinate coordMax() {}

 /** 
 * @return max distance using n points
 * I would maybe try to go for a recursive solution 
 * and already have the 2 corner cases down.
 */
public double statMaxDistance(int n) {

    if (n == 0)
        return coordTable[0].distance(coordTable[coordTable.length - 1]);
    if (n == 1)
        return coordTable[0].distance(coordMax());

    // TODO recursive step

    return statMaxDistance();
}
```

The question is :

Is there a way to complete this task without iterating over each point of the whole path, one by one, trying all possible combinations, computing all possible distances to eventually end up with the farthest one ?

It would seem rather sensical to follow such an approach where only 1 or 2 points would shift along the whole path but such an algorithm would be quite greedy when computing the maximum distance given 3+ reference points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using a Dynamic Program. Assume that `D[i][j]` is the maximum distance you can get from the start point to the `i`-th intermediate point where the last point is `j`. Your solution will be `D[n][endPoint]`.

So how to solve this? The first column `D[0][...]` is easy to calculate. This will just be the distances of the according point to the start point. The other columns are a bit trickier. You need to check all entries in the previous column where the last point is strictly before the current point. So, to calculate entry `D[i][j]`, you have to calculate:

```
D[i][j] = max_{k < j} (D[i - 1][k] + distance(k, j))
```

This means: Iterate all possible `k` such that `k` is smaller than `j` (i.e. the point `k` is located before the current point `j`). Calculate the resulting distance as the sum of the distance up to `k` (this is the `D[i - 1][k]` part) and the distance from `k` to `j`. Put the maximum of these values into `D[i][j]`. You may also want to keep track of `k` if you need to reconstruct the path at the end (i.e. you are not just interested in the maximum distance). Note that there may be cells with no valid solutions (e.g. `D[1][0]` - you cannot get to point `0` as the second (index `1`) intermediate point).

Do this for every intermediate point in every column up to `D[n - 1][...]`. The final step is to do this process once more for `D[n][endPoint]`, which strictly speaking does not need to be located in the `D` array (because you are interested in only a single value, not an entire column).

Once you have calculated this value, that is your solution. If you want to find the actual path, you have to backtrack using the stored `k` values for every cell.